# SQL values from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Okay so I have two tables in one database. One is called `accounts` and one is called `settings`. Through **one** query I would like to fetch `settings.positionX`, `settings.positionY` and `accounts.lastlogin`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: read about `join` keyword in MySQL

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question like this. Please share your tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for that sample.

Comment: if you add table structure of both tables  or how they are related in your question it will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what conditions you want all we can do is guess.. But here is what you need to do.

If you want only the records that match in accounts and settings then:

```
SELECT settings.positionX, settings.positionY, accounts.lastlogin
FROM settings 
INNER JOIN accounts
ON settings.condition = accounts.condition
```

if you want all the records from accounts (or settings) then join only the matching records then you want a `LEFT JOIN` / `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT settings.positionX, settings.positionY, accounts.lastlogin
FROM settings 
LEFT JOIN accounts
ON settings.condition = accounts.condition
```

You can see a visual representation of these joins [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: ``LEFT JOIN `accounts` ON settings.accountid=accounts.id`` settings.accountid and accounts.id have to be the same datatype and everything right?

Comment: indeed. they have to be the same.

Comment: Great it's working thanks to the link provided. One last thing though, 'lastlogin' is outputted as: `2016-05-28 12:20:02` how can I convert  to seconds? TIME_TO_SEC or TOSECONDS isn't working for me.